# How to prevent duplicate entry key when update

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

## Problem explain

I won't update the last primary key of the 3 primary key concatenate. But the problem is sometimes the first and second primary key was the same for multiple records. And in this case, when I set my new value I have a duplicate entry key even I use sub-request to avoid that problem.

## Some Code

### Schemas

```sql
create table llx_element_contact
(
    rowid             int auto_increment
        primary key,
    datecreate        datetime           null,
    statut            smallint default 5 null,
    element_id        int                not null,
    fk_c_type_contact int                not null,
    fk_socpeople      int                not null,
    constraint idx_element_contact_idx1
        unique (element_id, fk_c_type_contact, fk_socpeople)
)
```

### Update request

this request return duplicate key error

```sql
update llx_element_contact lec
set lec.fk_socpeople = 64
where 
-- Try to avoid the error by non including the values that are the same
(select count(*)
 from llx_element_contact ec
 where ec.fk_socpeople = 64
   and ec.element_id = lec.element_id
   and ec.fk_c_type_contact = lec.fk_c_type_contact) = 0
```

### Test data

```
rowid, datecreate, statut, element_id, fk_c_type_contact, fk_sockpeople
65,2015-08-31 18:59:18,4,65,160,30
66,2015-08-31 18:59:18,4,66,159,12
67,2015-08-31 18:59:18,4,67,160,12
15283,2016-03-23 11:47:15,4,6404,160,39
15284,2016-03-23 11:51:30,4,6404,160,58
```

Comment: The "dup error" problem is 2 last rows in data example. After updating both will have `(element_id, fk_c_type_contact, fk_socpeople) = (6404,160,64)`, but this combination is defined as UNIQUE. You are **the only** who can say what must be performed in this case. One of the rows (what precisely?) must stay unchanged? something else? This is not a problem of SQL code, it is a problem of the lack of an algorithm. And it must be solved out of the code.

Comment: Does it make sense to update a field to 64 based on a query which filter that table for elements where the same field is = 64?

Comment: @Akina I want to change the first one based on the most recent date

Comment: @JaimeDrq I don't have include my filter because is not the purpose of this question but of course in my actual database I have some condition to do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check only two other members of unique constraint as you're trying to assign the same value to the 3d member. No more then one row with the same two members must exist.

```
update llx_element_contact lec
set lec.fk_socpeople = 64
where 
-- Try to avoid the error by non including the values that are the same
(select count(*)
 from llx_element_contact ec
 where ec.element_id = lec.element_id
   and ec.fk_c_type_contact = lec.fk_c_type_contact) <=1
```

or

```
update llx_element_contact lec
set lec.fk_socpeople = 64
where 
-- Try to avoid the error by non including the values that are the same
 not exists (select 1
 from llx_element_contact ec
 where ec.element_id = lec.element_id
   and ec.fk_c_type_contact = lec.fk_c_type_contact
   and lec.fk_socpeople != ec.fk_socpeople)
```

Comment: `'You can't specify target table 'lec' for update in FROM clause'` for both variants

Comment: @Akina I don't have get the issus

Comment: @MrSolarius What is **precise** server version? some MariaDB, 10.3 or above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

You can prevent the `unique` conflict using `left join` to check that the corresponding row doesn't already exist:

```
update llx_element_contact lec left join
       (select element_id, fk_c_type_contact
        from llx_element_contact lec2
        where lec2.fk_socpeople = 64
        group by element_id, fk_c_type_contact
       ) lec2
       using (element_id, fk_c_type_contact)
    set lec.fk_socpeople = 64
    where lec2.element_id is null;
```

Your query has additional logic in it that is not explained.  It is not necessary for what you are asking.

Comment: thanks for your rapid answer however when I try your request in my database I continue to have a duplicate entry error.
with this data : 
`15409,2016-03-24 11:19:46,4,7122,160,61      15407,2016-03-24 11:04:50,4,7122,160,62`

Comment: @MrSolarius . . . You **cannot** have a duplicate entry.  There is a unique constraint.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT rowid, 
       SUM(fk_socpeople = 64) OVER (PARTITION BY element_id, fk_c_type_contact) u_flag,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY element_id, fk_c_type_contact ORDER BY datecreate DESC) u_rn
FROM llx_element_contact
)
update llx_element_contact lec
JOIN cte USING (rowid)
set lec.fk_socpeople = 64 
where cte.u_flag = 0
  AND cte.u_rn = 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08e20328ccc6187716084ce9d78816b0

Comment: Thanks for itroduce me at dbfiddle I don't know and it's realy cool :) And your request works too for me =D

Comment: @MrSolarius There is a lot of online fiddles for DBMSs, programming languages, regular expressions...